# how to store a result from mutl ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am using ng-repeat with filter and I am trying to store the ng-repeat list .
Here is my code.

```
<div ng-repeat="itemDate in itemList()|filter:'dispatch'|unique:'date'">
       <div>{{(itemDate.dateTimeStamp)}}</div>   
        <div ng-repeat="item in itemList() |filter:'dispatch'">     
            <div ng-show="itemDate.date === item.date">   
                <div>
                    {{item.desc}}{{item.code}}{{item.price}}
                </div>           
            </div>      
        </div>    
    </div>
```

itemList() i sthe list coming from service.I am trying to store the filterd list in an array. How do I keep the filtered list?

Comment: I think you do not understand what an angular filter is. It is not to filter results, its to change the view of the data so it is formatted for the user. See the [angular date filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) as an example, it formats the date in the view for the presentation. If you want to narrow down an array you should do that in a controller and persist the changed array there. Filters are for presentation logic.

Answer (score 0):

A filter that you are referring to is a view filter for the ng-repeat's rendering loop.

Therefore, the filter is only applied to the data that is being displayed in the DOM. What you are looking to do is update the original data based on the filters provided in your controller, or potentially use that filter as a provider.

controller:

```
angular.module('myRandomModule')
  .controller('SomeControllerWithAFilterInjected', ['$filter', '$scope',  SomeControllerWithAFilterInjectedFn]);

function SomeControllerWithAFilterInjectedFn($filter, $scope) {
  $scope.arrayOfDataUsedInMyNgRepeat = ['foo', 'bar', 'so', 'many', 'elements'];

  $scope.objectWhichHasABunchOfPropsBoundToNgModelsForFilteringThatIsUsedInYourFilter = {};

  $scope.filteredArray = function() {
    return $filter('nameOfThatFilterIMadeOneDay')($scope.arrayOfDataUsedInMyNgRepeat, $scope.objectWhichHasABunchOfPropsBoundToNgModelsForFilteringThatIsUsedInYourFilter);
  }
}
```

[Here is an excellent link to some examples of filters used in controllers.](http://codewala.net/2015/07/01/how-to-use-angular-filter-controller-factory-service/)

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. I will try this.